# What does it mean to clear cut images?

Tags: images, terminology

I found a job posting that says they have images that need to be 'clear cut', mostly of clothes, products, etc.  Does anyone know what that means?

Comment: Did you try messaging the person to ask for clarification?

Comment: most likely, it means "silhouetting" (aka "masking").

Comment: Yea, sounds like a silly, contrived way to say "background masking".

Answer (score 1):

Clear cut means to erase the background around a product. Here's an example: http://www.designjane.com/photo-clear-cut-photoshop-enhancements

Comment: I can't say I've ever heard that term used in the industry, though that link certainly makes it appear that it's used by at least one person. I've always used the term "masking".

Comment: +1 "clear cut", "cut out", "mask" are all terms people will use for this. Clients don't always know the exact terms. In doubt, there's no shame in asking "do you mean you want me to remove or mask the background?" ;)

Comment: Its also soul destroying... dont apply!!!!